# CentOS: unable to verify backported fixes

Tags: centos, rpm

Generally one uses rpm to verify backported fixes to a package like:

> rpm -q --changelog httpd

But on my CentOS server, it's giving me:

> package httpd is not installed

Or:

> package php is not installed

For any package, even though the package is installed. Am I missing something?

Comment: How are you determining that it's installed via a `rpm`?

Comment: @jordanm I'm not; how can I check for backported fixes if it's not from rpm?

Comment: Exactly how did these packages get onto your system?

Comment: @MichaelHampton It's been a while, but I believe yum or they came with the system from our provider.

Comment: If they were installed with yum, I don't think you would be having this problem.

Comment: Does httpd show up in the list of installed packages from `rpm -q -a`?